# How to custom animation for collectionviewcell's deletion?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionviewcell

The default collectionview deleteItems will fade out the cell, I want to change this animation to let the cell fly out of the screen like Tinder app. Please help

```
self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
     self.likedArrayData?.append(self.arrayData![indexPath.item])
     self.arrayData?.remove(at: indexPath.item)
     self.collectionView.deleteItems(at:[indexPath])                    
}, completion: { [unowned self] (_) in

})
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
let cell = self.collectionView!.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
                    cell?.center.y -= 500 // Move up 500 pixels
                    cell?.alpha = 0.0 //the cell will come back from top so I set al[ha to 0.0
                }, completion: { (_) in
                    self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
                        self.likedArrayData?.append(self.arrayData![indexPath.item])
                        self.arrayData?.remove(at: indexPath.item)
                        self.collectionView.deleteItems(at:[indexPath])
                    }, completion: { [unowned self] (_) in

                    })
                })
```